# Can't create a folder/subfolder with mkdir from home

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to create a folder called `hello` and a sub folder located inside `hello` called `world`. I've tried `mkdir $HOME/hello/world` but it does not work saying that it cannot create directory since no such file or directory exists. If I try `$HOME/hello` I am able to create a folder called `hello` inside `$HOME`. How do I go about doing this? I do not want to use `-p` to create the needed parent folders if they are missing.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using the feature added to `mkdir` to make it easy to do?  That's kinda silly.  (And `mkdir -p` is standard on POSIX systems.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use the `-p` flag to `mkdir`, but if you insist, you could do this:

```
mkdir $HOME/hello $HOME/hello/world
```

Comment: That works fine if `$HOME/hello` doesn't exist; if it does, it leads to error messages.  Of course, one of the benefits of `mkdir -p` is that it does not complain about pre-existing directories — but your hand is partially tied by the question (and the question is silly in making that constraint).